# Hiding data travelling in url

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I am new in web development. I am working on my course project making a website in which i am traveling the data in url. I want to hide that data from there for the user so that they can not change it in the future. 
I am working on ASP.net. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide the data travelling in the url 
but you can encrypt data in url
like my url is text.aspx?Firstname=Robin&LastName=Hood
then is should show like test.aspx?Firstname=121sdnasdkjn121928&LastName=sadklsdn12981029
something like that 
and then where you are getting data you need to decrypt that data and it will return actual data

here are the functions for encryption or decryption

```
 public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        try
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        try
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText.Replace(" ", "+"));

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

OR

You can use term url routing as well to hide real url and show fake url to user 
like instead of localhost:1544/test.aspx it will show localhost:1544/test or localhost:1544/what_ever_you_want 
it will hide .aspx extension as well

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the data travelling in the url. The most simple way to send data that does not show in the url is by using POST requests instead of GET requests.